# What is SWIFT_ENFORCE_EXCLUSIVE_ACCESS in Swift 4?

Tags: swift

What is exclusive access to memory and what do the different options mean?

[This proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0176-enforce-exclusive-access-to-memory.md) explains it but perhaps someone can provide a simpler interpretation and the practical implications/dangers of the different options?

Comment: See [Memory Safety](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/MemorySafety.html) in the Swift book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclusive access is a policy for preventing multiple access of the same memory address at the same time.

The below is not a conflict because x is read in one moment, and changed in another.

```
var x: String = "Hello,"
x = x + " world!"
```

But, consider this:

```
extension String {
  mutating func replace(_ function: () -> String) {
    self = function()  
  }
}

var x: String = "Hello,"
x.replace { x + " world!" }
```

A mutating function takes write access to the variable, the closure captures the variable which tries to read while it's being written, which violates exclusive memory access.

So the compiler flag is there to present an error when it catches you doing this, to stop you from making the mistake. (the mistake is because the behaviour is undefined)

Read more under "Conflicting Access to Properties": https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/MemorySafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH46-ID571